# add import to a groovy file from an eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I want to add some import statements in a groovy class via my plugin.
I m trying to do

```
compilationUnit.createImport(type.getFullyQualifiedName(), null, null);
```

where type is what i want to import. I get a null pointer exception. I 
am using the same code for a Java class and it works.
Can somebody suggest me what could be wrong.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit as to what you want to do?  Are you trying to add the text 'import foo.bar.*' to the top of your groovy file?  Is this some kind of refactoring?

Comment: i have a plugin from which i want to add imports to a groovy file...For instance, i want to create a List<Perosn>, then i want to create an import for ex. import com.Person, into the groovy file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to properly add an import to a file using proper APIs, then your best bet is to use `greclipse.org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.rewrite.ImportRewrite`, which is a groovy-eclipse variant of a JDT class of the same name.

Look in `org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring.actions.OrganizeGroovyImports` for an example of how to use it.

You can create it like this:

```
ImportRewrite rewriter = CodeStyleConfiguration.createImportRewrite(unit, false);
```

And then, add your import:

```
rewriter.addImport(qualifiedClassName);
```

And then do the rewrite:

```
TextEdit edit = rewriter.rewriteImports(null);
unit.applyTextEdit(edit, null);
```

Things are a little bit trickier if you want to add static, star, or aliased imports, but you can look at the code for that.

Comment: Thank u so much. will try it out and get back